# How to make meld prefer an SVN diff over a CVS diff

Tags: svn, cvs, meld

We have some directories that are tracked in both CVS and SVN (loooong story). When I change a file in one of these and run meld it diffs it against the SVN version. However for some of the other developers it diffs against CVS. Is there a way to specify which one gets priority?
Everyone is using Meld 1.3.0

edit: Ok, I see now that there is an option on the address bar in the directory view to select however some of the machines don't have that bar.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in Meld. See the related [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=479644).

Anyway, this sounds like a configuration issue. In the current released version of Meld (1.5.1), there's an drop-down-menu item in the ui to select the version control system.